# Magento API SOAP v2 : faultcode Receiver, faultstring Uknown Error

Tags: magento-1.8, api, soap

I'm getting a SOAP error (v2, WS-I Compliant) that I'm having trouble debugging. I'm getting a "Receiver, Unknown Error", which the header shows to be a 500 Server Error and appears as such in my nginx logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2015:18:20:18 +0000] "GET /index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 354035 "-" "-"
12.123.1.12 - - [02/Jan/2015:18:20:18 +0000] "POST /index.php/api/v2_soap/index/ HTTP/1.1" 500 273 "-" "PHP"
```

I can do other calls, for instance a *salesOrderInfo* request will work, but this *salesOrderCreateInvoice* fails.

Any suggestions on how to debug something so vague?

**LAST REQUEST HEADERS:**

```
POST /index.php/api/v2_soap/index/ HTTP/1.1
Host: shop.example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 489
Cookie: PHPSESSID=q2fsubqee1r43kdoa1v3o3eai0;CUSTOMER=deleted;CUSTOMER_INFO=deleted;CUSTOMER_AUTH=deleted;
```

**LAST REQUEST:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:salesOrderInvoiceCreateRequestParam>
    <sessionId>2cb4af977b083e51b64e1a2f156136fa</sessionId>
    <invoiceIncrementId>200000255</invoiceIncrementId>
        <itemsQty>
            <complexObjectArray>
                <order_item_id>985</order_item_id>
                <qty>1</qty>
            </complexObjectArray>
        </itemsQty>
    </ns1:salesOrderInvoiceCreateRequestParam>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**LAST RESPONSE HEADERS:**

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Service Error
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Fri, 02 Jan 2015 16:33:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 273
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.33
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=q2fsubqee1r43kdoa1v3o3eai0; expires=Fri, 02-Jan-2015 16:48:04 GMT; path=/; domain=shop.example.com; secure; httponly
Set-Cookie: CUSTOMER=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=shop.example.com; secure; httponly
Set-Cookie: CUSTOMER_INFO=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=shop.example.com; secure; httponly
Set-Cookie: CUSTOMER_AUTH=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=shop.example.com; secure; httponly
```

**LAST RESPONSE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <faultcode>Receiver</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Unknown error</faultstring>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My tips for debugging SOAP calls:

**Disable WSDL Cache**

Under System > Configuration > Magento Core API set Enable WSDL Cache to "No".

**Write a basic PHP script for your calls**

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$apiUrl = ''; //your api data
$apiUser = ''; //your api data
$apiPass = ''; //your api data
$client = new SoapClient($apiUrl, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'trace' => 1, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$sessionId = $client->login($apiUser, $apiPass);
//some more SOAP calls
```

**Debug SOAP request/response**

You can debug with `$client->__getLastRequest()` or `$client->__getLastResponse()`

**Check your logs for any error messages/notices**

Check if there are any SOAP call error messages in your logs that might help tracing down the problem.

**Debug**

If nothing helps, check what data is received by the API. Check out the `Api.php` and/or `Api/V2.php` files of the specific modules.