# Client wsdl Magento 2 internal error

Tags: magento2, wsdl

I am trying call to web service, but when I load the code Magento return an Internal Error.

I only add this code:

```
$soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client('http://www.transzuri.com/ws/combx/st/?wsdl');

// $soapResponse = $soapClient->PresupuestosDisponibles( array('GUID' => '6BB98E9E-6131-4CB3-9C38-C93458B691F4', 'CodigoPostal' => '03440', 'PaisISO' => 'ES') );
$soapResponse = $soapClient->getTest(array('GUID' => '6BB98E9E-6131-4CB3-9C38-C93458B691F4'));
```

But the page load this:

[image]

The error is in exception.log:

```
Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-588b1719eb933; Message: Unknown Reason in /var/www/transzuri/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/transzuri/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(SoapFault))
#1 /var/www/transzuri/app/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest.php(219): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(SoapFault))
#2 /var/www/transzuri/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /var/www/transzuri/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /var/www/transzuri/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#5 /var/www/transzuri/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#6 {main} [] []
```

Where is the problem and Why?

Comment: There is no method `getTest` in your wsdl url. check the appropriate method and then try. this url `http://www.transzuri.com/ws/combx/st/?wsdl` xml file listed all the methods. choose one and then try

Comment: Sorry I put the code while I did probes and I put the incorrect method. I edit yet. The error put Unknow Reason

Comment: Try this link - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49964/magento-api-soap-v2-faultcode-receiver-faultstring-uknown-error

check basic soap is worked or not ?

Comment: But, I not create a ws. I only use one diferent. I not need this I think